# Access data in package subdirectory

Tags: python, package

I am writing a python package with modules that need to open data files in a `./data/` subdirectory. Right now I have the paths to the files hardcoded into my classes and functions. I would like to write more robust code that can access the subdirectory regardless of where it is installed on the user's system.

I've tried a variety of methods, but so far I have had no luck. It seems that most of the "current directory" commands return the directory of the system's python interpreter, and not the directory of the module.

This seems like it ought to be a trivial, common problem. Yet I can't seem to figure it out. Part of the problem is that my data files are not `.py` files, so I can't use import functions and the like.

Any suggestions?

Right now my package directory looks like:

```
/
__init__.py
module1.py
module2.py
data/   
   data.txt
```

I am trying to access `data.txt` from `module*.py`!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `__file__` to get the path to the package, like this:

```
import os
this_dir, this_filename = os.path.split(__file__)
DATA_PATH = os.path.join(this_dir, "data", "data.txt")
print open(DATA_PATH).read()
```

Comment: This will not work if the files are in a distribution (IE. egg). Use pkg_resources to get at the data file.

Comment: Indeed, this is broken.

Comment: Also, `__file__` doesn't work with py2exe, as the value will be the path to the zip file.

Comment: This actually worked for me. Did not have any problems. I am using python 3.6

Comment: This will not work in case of distribution (egg etc).

Answer (score 195):

The standard way to do this is with setuptools packages and pkg_resources.

You can lay out your package according to the following hierarchy, and configure the package setup file to point it your data resources, as per this link:

http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data

You can then re-find and use those files using pkg_resources, as per this link:

http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PkgResources#basic-resource-access

```
import pkg_resources

DATA_PATH = pkg_resources.resource_filename('<package name>', 'data/')
DB_FILE = pkg_resources.resource_filename('<package name>', 'data/sqlite.db')
```

Comment: I think that this is the preferred way, I'm not entirely sure of the reason but projects show warnings when you refer to the package/module with `__file__`.

Comment: Won't *pkg_resources* create a run-time dependency on *setuptools*? For example, I redistribute a Debian package so why would I depend on `python-setuptools` just for that? So far `__file__` works fine for me.

Comment: Why this is better: The ResourceManager class provides uniform access to package resources, whether those resources exist as files and directories or are compressed in an archive of some kind

Comment: Brilliant suggestion, thanks. I implemented a standard file open using `from pkg_resources import resource_filename open(resource_filename('data', 'data.txt'), 'rb')`

Comment: How will this work for using the package when it isn't installed? Just testing locally I mean

Comment: @VardhanVarma this isn't better.  the setuptools devs are just not on board with fixing this bug as they are in denial about it being a bug.

Comment: In python 3.7, `importlib.resources` replaces `pkg_resources` for this purpose (because of performance problems).

Comment: @benjimin also `importlib_resources` for python < 3.7

Comment: perfect solution. `pkg_resources` also helps when you have multiple resource files that you need to manage (`resource_listdir`) + some more options

Comment: This works in Python 3.10 but fails in 3.9 with a `TypeError`.  [This solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26278544/1717828) worked in that case.

Answer (score 35):

There is often not point in making an answer that details code that does *not* work as is, but I believe this to be an exception. Python 3.7 added [`importlib.resources`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources) that is supposed to replace `pkg_resources`. It would work for accessing files within packages that do not have *slashes* in their names, i.e.

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    module1.py
    module2.py
    data/   
       data.txt
    data2.txt
```

i.e. you could access `data2.txt` inside package `foo` with for example

```
importlib.resources.open_binary('foo', 'data2.txt')
```

but it would fail with an exception for

```
>>> importlib.resources.open_binary('foo', 'data/data.txt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/resources.py", line 87, in open_binary
    resource = _normalize_path(resource)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/resources.py", line 61, in _normalize_path
    raise ValueError('{!r} must be only a file name'.format(path))
ValueError: 'data/data2.txt' must be only a file name
```

This cannot be fixed except by placing `__init__.py` in `data` and then using it as a package:

```
importlib.resources.open_binary('foo.data', 'data.txt')
```

The reason for this behaviour is ["it is by design"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsGFU2qh73E&feature=youtu.be&t=515); but [the design might change](https://gitlab.com/python-devs/importlib_resources/issues/58#note_239062875)...

Comment: Do you have a better link for *"it is by design"* than a youtube video — preferably one with text?

Comment: @gerrit the 2nd one does contain text. `"This was a deliberate choice, but I think you have a valid use case.  @brettcannon what do you think?  And if we allow this, should we make sure it gets into Python 3.7?"`

Comment: The design has now changed to traversable APIs (avail in stdlib Python 3.9+). Further details in the dupe here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/58941536/674039

Answer (score 17):

To provide a solution working today. Definitely use this API to not reinvent all those wheels.

A true filesystem filename is needed. Zipped eggs will be extracted to a cache directory:

```
from pkg_resources import resource_filename, Requirement

path_to_vik_logo = resource_filename(Requirement.parse("enb.portals"), "enb/portals/reports/VIK_logo.png")
```

Return a readable file-like object for the specified resource; it may be an actual file, a StringIO, or some similar object. The stream is in “binary mode”, in the sense that whatever bytes are in the resource will be read as-is.

```
from pkg_resources import resource_stream, Requirement

vik_logo_as_stream = resource_stream(Requirement.parse("enb.portals"), "enb/portals/reports/VIK_logo.png")
```

Package Discovery and Resource Access using pkg_resources

- https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#resource-extraction
- https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#basic-resource-access

Answer (score 8):

You need a name for your whole module, you're given directory tree doesn't list that detail, for me this worked:

```
import pkg_resources
print(    
    pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, 'data/data.txt')
)
```

Notibly setuptools does not appear to resolve files based on a name match with packed data files, soo you're gunna have to include the `data/` prefix pretty much no matter what. You can use `os.path.join('data', 'data.txt)` if you need alternate directory separators, Generally I find no compatibility problems with hard-coded unix style directory separators though.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/distutils/setupscript.html#writing-the-setup-script
> Note that any pathnames (files or directories) supplied in the setup script should be written using the Unix convention, i.e. slash-separated. The Distutils will take care of converting this platform-neutral representation into whatever is appropriate on your current platform before actually using the pathname. This makes your setup script portable across operating systems, which of course is one of the major goals of the Distutils. In this spirit, all pathnames in this document are slash-separated.

Answer (score 6):

I think I hunted down an answer.

I make a module data_path.py, which I import into my other modules containing:

```
data_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'data')
```

And then I open all my files with

```
open(os.path.join(data_path,'filename'), <param>)
```

Comment: This will fail to work when the resource is in an archive distribution (such as a zipped egg).  Prefer something like that: `pkg_resources.resource_string('pkg_name', 'data/file.txt')`

Comment: @ankostis setuptools is clever enough to extract the archive if it detects that you used `__file__` somewhere. In my case I use a library which really wants paths and not streams. Of course I could write the files temporarily to disk but being lazy I just use setuptools's feature.