# add data files to python projects setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I have a project like this:

```
├── CHANGES.txt
├── LICENSE
├── MANIFEST.in
...
├── docs
│   └── index.rst
├── negar
│   ├── Negar.py
│   ├── Virastar.py
│   ├── Virastar.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── untouchable.dat
│   ├── gui.py
│   ├── gui.pyc
│   ├── i18n
│   │   ├── fa_IR.qm
│   │   └── fa_IR.ts
│   └── negar.pro
├── setup.py
...
```

and inside that my file `Virastar.py` need some data from `data.untouchable.dat`. it works fine until I install the project with this `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    ...
    include_package_data=True,
    packages = find_packages() + ['negar'],
    package_dir={'negar': 'negar'},
    package_data={'negar': ['data/*.dat']},
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'negar = negar.Negar:main',
        ],
    }, 
    ...  
)
```

after that when I start my program and when it needs that data file it return this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/untochable.dat'
```

even in my `egg-info` sources I can't find any data file:

```
...
negar/Negar.py
negar/Virastar.py
negar/__init__.py
negar/gui.py
negar/data/__init__.py
```

have I missed something here?

Thank you all.

EDIT: Do I have to add any special thing in **init**.py?

and I have to add this: I used untouchable.dat just like this:

```
f = codecs.open('data/untouchable.dat', encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: in python 2.7 they changed the way to include files to MANIFEST.in or something - I'm not sure and didn't use it but it could be a direction

Comment: I'm in python 2.6! and for some reasons I can't upgrade now!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first problem is that I didn't import my data file into the package with `MANIFEST.in` file. I imported it like this:

```
include negar/data/*.dat
```

After that my data file already imported with my package install. but because I had mistakes in open my data files, python couldn't find it. this question helped me to find the right way 
[Python Access Data in Package Subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/779495/1573477) and now I use something like this:

```
import os
this_dir, this_filename = os.path.split(__file__)
DATA_PATH = os.path.join(this_dir, "data", "data.txt")
print open(DATA_PATH).read()
```

Comment: in which file did you add the lines `import os ...`?

Answer (score 22):

I used [data_files](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#distutils-additional-files)

```
data_files = [('', ['negar/data/untouchable.dat'])],
```

Comment: For those wondering where the file will go: installation destination will be `sys.prefix`. Suggest replacing `''` with a dir-name to make some sense for the destination.

Comment: @JariTurkia Ah. So, are you suggesting `('negar/data', ['untouchable.dat'])`?

Comment: On the tuple, left side is destination, right side is source file. By having the destination as empty, during setup the file will be placed in the root of your Python's prefix. My suggestion is to have a directory like this: `[('negar/data', ['negar/data/untouchable.dat'])]`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try:

```
package_data={'negar/data': ['data/*.dat']},
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that does **not** require any of:

- `MANIFEST.in`
- `include_package_data=True`
- `package_dir={}`
- and neither the `__init__.py` file in the folder!

Having the project like:

```
├── CHANGES.txt
├── LICENSE
...
├── negar
│   ├── Negar.py
│   ├── Virastar.py
│   ├── Virastar.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── untouchable.dat
│   ├── subfolder
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── data_NOT_included
│   │   │   └── garbage.toml
│   │   └── data_with_no_init_file
│   │       ├── config.ini
│   │       └── options.yml
│   ├── gui.py
│   ├── gui.pyc
│   ├── i18n
│   │   ├── fa_IR.qm
│   │   └── fa_IR.ts
│   └── negar.pro
├── setup.py
...
```

The setup file:

```
setup(
    ...
    packages = find_packages()
    package_data= {
        # all .dat files at any package depth
        '': ['**/*.dat'],

        # into the data folder (being into a module) but w/o the init file
        'negar.subfolder': [ '**/*.ini', '**/*.yml', ]
        
    },
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'negar = negar.Negar:main',
        ],
    }, 
    ...
)
```

This worked great in my case and I avoided maintaining an additional `MANIFEST.in` file.

> **caveat:** the "negar.subfolder" has to be a python module.

---

To the access the file:

```
from importlib.resources import files
config = files('negar.subfolder').joinpath('data_with_no_init_file').joinpath('config.ini').read_text()
```

from [accessing-data-files-at-runtime](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html#accessing-data-files-at-runtime)