# How to make non python files (xlsx, json, etc.) available to package for pip install?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

Is it possible to point to package dependent files with extensions other than `.py` in a `setup.py` file?

```
Package/
         __init__.py
         file.py
         file.xlsx
```

After pip installing, I want to be able to access `file.xlsx` somehow through `import Package`. Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7522250/6340496).  And definitely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12191339/6340496).

Comment: Thank you @S3DEV have a good one

Comment: Looks like MANIFEST.in https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html works.