# How do I access data files with pkg_resources?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, pkg-resources

My package looks somewhat like this.

```
Package
   tokenizer,py
   corpus.py
   __init__.py
   resources
     data.txt
```

I want to access data.txt from corpus.py. How should I do it with pkg_resources? Also do I need to create setup.py for package resources to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Access Data in Package Subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779495/python-access-data-in-package-subdirectory)

Comment: If you don't have `setup.py` you don't have a package. And if you don't have a package you don't need `pkg_resources`. See the accepted answer at the link above.

Comment: Please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71677490/how-to-properly-include-data-folder-to-python-package

Comment: Please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71677490/how-to-properly-include-data-folder-to-python-package