# How to properly include data folder to python package

Tags: python, pip

I'm building a small python package that I deploy to our internal pypi server to be easily installable with `pip`. I'm using `setup.py` to build the tar.gz archive to upload there.
And I need to include some additional data - to be more specific, I use `nltk` in my project and I want to ship the package with specific `nltk` data already downloaded, since it doesn't make sense to me to make the person using my package responsible for downloading it themself. So I have the following structure

```
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── my_pkg
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── my_module.py
│   │   └── resources
│   │       └── nltk_data
|   |           └─... too many subfolders and files
```

And I would like to include the whole `nltk_data` subfolder to be in the same place once the package is installed. I managed to get working `package_data={'my_pkg' :['./resources/file.dat']},` for one file, but I don't know how to do the same with complex directory structure with many subfolder, subsubfolders, file of different extensions etc. Is there any way to do this?

My setup.py is quite simple (I omitted things such as description or URL for simplicity)

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='some-cool-name',
    version="1.0.0",
    classifiers=[],
    
    packages=find_packages(where='src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    package_data={'my_pkg' :[]},
    include_package_data=True,
    py_modules=[],

    python_requires='>=3.8',
    install_requires=['nltk==3.6.5']
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply specify the relative path to the data you want to include. You need to put an `__init__.py`-file in both subfolders though, but then it should work.

```
package_data={'my_pkg' :['my_pkg/resources/nltk_data/*']}
```

To use the data in your script, use `importlib` (for example [`importlib.read_text`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.resources.read_text)) to open your desired file.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the `__init__.py` in subfolders, that's quite surprising to me.

Answer (score 3):

A while after I posted this question, I encountered another solution, that was not mentioned here and seemed quite elegant, so I will put it here in case someone finds it useful.
File `MANIFEST.in` in the top level of the directory structure, next to setup.py, can do the same easily, with

```
recursive-include src/my_pkg/resources *
```

Comment: could you explain a bit more your solution, please? How do you run that command? Do you link the manifest file to the pip upload somehow?

Comment: To be honest, I don't remember much, some "reverse engineering" from bash history told me I used the command `python setup.py sdist upload -r local` (as I was uploading to the local pip server and have specified the URL in pip config file) and I think it just used the MANIFEST.in file by default because of some naming convention (but again, this is just my guess based on what I remember)