# Find data files in python3 wheel

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging, python-wheel

.I am packaging a wheel which includes data files and I need to be able to get their path.

I have successfully added the files to the project using:

```
setup.py file:
    from setuptools import setup
    setup(..., 
          data_files=[('data', glob('data/**'))],
          ...)

$ python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

This gives me a wheel which (when unzipped) looks like:

```
my_project-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
├── my_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── awesome_feature.py
├── my_project-0.0.0.data
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── config.txt
│   │   ├── important_params.csv
│   │   ├── large_data_blob.dat
```

How can I reliably locate the data files from within this project?

In particular, projects which depend on `my_project` will need to use these files and I need some way of finding the path of the `data` folder and returning it to projects that depend on `my_project`

EDIT: I've tried locating the data with pkg_resources, but not had any luck. Following `pip3 install my_project-0.0.0.whl` none of the data that was in the wheel seems to be in the installed package (judging by disk-usage).

I included the function:

```
def get_data_path():
    import pkg_resources
    return pkg_resources.resource_filename('my_project', 'data')
```

The path that returns is: `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/my_project/data`, but that path doesn't exist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Access Data in Package Subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779495/python-access-data-in-package-subdirectory)

Comment: See the answers about `pkg_resources`.